# \cite{} autocompletion in VIM in non tex file

Tags: bibtex, vim, markdown, vim-latex

I'm moving my workflow from LaTeX to Asciidoc + Asciidoc-bib. I would like to have the vim-latex reference autocompletion working for non-`.tex` files, in my case for .txt files. So when I add some clues to `\cite{}` and do control-x control-o it shows me the available citations for some BibTeX file.

The only way I can think of doing this is by extracting the functions from the vim-latex suite and creating a new script, unfortunately my knowledge of vimscript is not great.

I've read about doing:

```
:set filetype=tex
```

but I'm afraid I will import all of vim-latex behaviour which I would like to avoid. Maybe if there is a way to disable (almost) all of vim-latex except the `\cite{` autocompletion it would be fine.

Comment: I decided to learn some VimScript and spent the last two days scavenging the relevant code from vim-latex. It works and now I'm making a standalone pluging out of it. As soon as it is finished I'll upload to github.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a plugin to complete citation tags for asciidoc documents.
[vim-autocite](https://github.com/GCBallesteros/vim-autocite)